# C3P0 configuration - numHelperThreads per connection pool

Tags: java, database, c3p0

In one of our solution we are creating poolbackedDatasources with C3P0 connection pooling. One thing we found out that all the connections from all pool are served by same numHelperThreads. Is there a way of having separate helper threads per pool? What is the way of separating numHelperThreads for each connection pool? What configuration parameters do we need to tweak if it is doable?

Comment: are you running multiple pools in one DataSource (i.e. are you calling `dataSource.getConnection( user, password )` with multiple `user` / `password` combinations?

Comment: We are using mybatis SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(config) to build a SqlSessionFactory. For each session we are calling SqlSessionFactory.openSession(). 

config for each SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(config) is instantiated with environment which has a pooledDataSources. Each dataSource has separate user and password. 

This was we have poolBacked datasource. But all dataSource is using the same helper threads.

Can we have separate helper threads set for each poolbacked DataSource?

Comment: any solution @SteveWaldman

Comment: The scope of the c3p0's Thread pool is one per DataSource. So you should already have what you want, if things are as you describe. I am unfamiliar with mybatis, so I can't comment on what your middleware is doing behind the scenes. But if you have multiple `PooledDataSource`s, you also have multiple Thread pools. If you are seeing too few Threads, maybe check JMX or call `C3P0Registry.getNumPooledDataSources()` to make sure you have as many DataSources as you think!

Comment: We have JMX metrics for the application and its showing application has 13 different datasources. And when we face "APPARENT DEADLOCK" situation we saw that numThreadsAwaitingCheckout for each data sources were the maximum number set by application. From this metric we got the idea that numHelperThreads are not per dataSources. If it was per dataSource, why would all the pools are waiting to getConnection at that point?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the maximum number set by application". It's easy to check the number of Threads directly. Use whatever tooling you have to review Threads in your VM, or go old school and use ctrl-\ or ctrl-break to get a Thread dump in a terminal. c3p0 helper threads look like `C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2zovqs9onn20rb77usm6|4b55818e]-HelperThread-#0`. There should be as many identity tokens as DataSources, for each as many Threads as `numHelperThreads`. p.s. what version of c3p0 are you using?